# Get the Minitest seed value programmatically

Tags: ruby, minitest

In RSpec I would use the following to obtain a `Random` which is seeded from the test order random seed. This would give us a reproducible RNG for things like fuzzing:

```rb
reproducible_random = Random.new(RSpec.configuration.seed)
```

Now that I am working with a project that uses Minitest (the Rails default) I can't seem to find how to obtain the Minitest seed value and produce a reproducible test. Is there a way to access it someplace from inside the tests themselves?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of [Minitest `5.16.0`](https://github.com/minitest/minitest/blob/master/History.rdoc#5160--2022-06-14-), the seed is available via `Minitest.seed`

Comment: Indeed, also just saw that

Answer (score 1):

There is an [open issue](https://github.com/seattlerb/minitest/pull/657) about it in mintest from 2016.

I believe as of now it is not possible.

Comment: Thanks, looks like it. I'll see if I can persuade Ryan to get some movement there.

Answer (score -2):

You can use the --seed parameter when calling minitest or the SEED environment variable, [source code](https://github.com/seattlerb/minitest/blob/fe3992e85b40792cf7bff2a876887d8d9e392068/lib/minitest.rb#L190

Comment: That I know, but how do I access this value from inside the test code? If the argument is not provided and the SEED envvar is not set I won't be able to grab them from there